# Find when a specific database went offline and the reason for same

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Find when a specific database went offline and the reason for same and when did it recover back.

All I know there is a SCOM alert set for the server and I got a notification as Database is offline and later when I checked I found it as online. So, I want to check at what time it went offline and how and when did it come online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At minimum, please check sql logs, for example, if I purposely take a db offline using

```
alter database [TestDB] set offline with rollback immediate;
```

I can see in SQL Server log, the following message

> Date      10/24/2016 12:28:57 PM Log      SQL Server (Current - 10/24/2016
>   12:00:00 AM)
>
> Source        spid51
>
> Message Setting database option OFFLINE to ON for database 'TestDB'.

Comment: We wont be able to find the reason as why it went offline and how did it come online ?

Comment: I am not sure about the "reason", but I think I would first figure out who / when gets the database offline and then make logic conclusion as to what is the reason behind who/when doing this. On the other hand, I believe using Extended Event (database_stopped event), you can automate the monitoring of who/when in kind of real-time.

Comment: You are very welcome, @Puskar !